# Как в таблице перебрать два объекта

Tags: java, html, thymeleaf

У меня есть таблица, в ней каждый столбец получается перебором массива, так вот мне надо сделать так, чтобы в этой же таблице отображались данные из другого массива, который по длине равный этому. Тоесть, чтобы колонка Author заполнялась из объекта authors значением полей user_id

```
<table>
    <thead>
    <tr>
        <th> ID </th>
        <th> Author </th>
        <th> Title </th>
        <th> Read </th>
        <th sec:authorize="hasAnyRole('MOD', 'ADMIN', 'SUPER_ADMIN')"> Delete </th>
    </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
    <!--<tr th:if="${news.empty}">
        <td colspan="2"> No News Available </td>
    </tr>-->
    <tr th:each="news : ${news}">
        <td><span th:text="${news.news_id}"> ID </span></td>
        <td><span th:text="${authors.user_id}"> Author </span></td> <!--TODO: Display author login-->
        <td><span th:text="${news.tittle}"> Tittle </span></td>
        <td><a href="id.html" th:href="@{http://localhost:8080/news/{id}(id = ${news.news_id})}"> Read </a></td>
        <td sec:authorize="hasAnyRole('MOD', 'ADMIN', 'SUPER_ADMIN')"><form action="news/delete" method="post"> <!--{id}(id = ${news.news_id})-->
            <input type="hidden" name="news_id" th:value="${news.news_id}" />
            <input type="submit" value="DELETE">
        </form>
        </td>
    </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

При данном варианте вылезает ошибка.

Comment: хм а разве не нужно скрипты писать в теге "<script>"?

Comment: Для чего? Данные заполняются на стороне сервера и пользователю отправлется заполненная данными html страница

Comment: В вопросе ничего не сказано про то что это работа с сервером, я думал речь о локальной html страничке

Comment: вставки thymeleaf, а также соответствующий тег об этом говорят, в любом случае, извиняюсь за введение в заблуждение.